# Getting variable doesn't exist error

Tags: apex, trigger, email

I'm working on a trigger to notify a user when there email changes, but am having trouble compiling it.  It's saying a variable doesn't existing, what am I doing wrong?

```
trigger email on Contact (before insert) {

    for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
        if(old.Email != c.Email){
         Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

            mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {c.Email});
            mail.setSubject('Test Mail Trigger');
            mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi  you have changed your email Id'+ old.Email +'to ' + c.Email);
        }
     }
    Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[]{mail}); **//Here I am getting error it says "Variable does not exists:mail"**
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you're getting the error message is because you have initialized the `mail` inside the If condition and you're referencing it outside the if condition. Also you're trigger was not bulkified. So first you should store your mail object in a list of type `messaging.singleSendEmail` and then invoke the `messaging.sendEmail()` method outside the for loop because there's a limit of 10 invocation to the `messaging.sendEmail()` method in a single apex execution.

```
list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> mailList = new list<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
 Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
    if(old.Email != c.Email){
     Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

        mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {c.Email});
        mail.setSubject('Test Mail Trigger');
        mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi  you have changed your email Id'+ old.Email +'to ' + c.Email);
        mailList.add(mail);
    }
 }
Messaging.sendEmail(mailList);
```

Comment: Thank.. for that "List" advice.....but now it shows same error in 3rd line  'c.Id' variable does not exists

Comment: Try using `before update` for executing code that detects a change.  The `before insert` is fired before the initial insert/creation of the record and not on subsequent updates.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing ID of a record which is not yet created.A Record have ID value only after creation.

So please run your trigger after update event.

This will solve your problem.

```
  trigger email on Contact (after update) {
  Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail;

  List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> messages = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
  for(Contact c : Trigger.new){
     Contact old = trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id);
     if(old.Email != c.Email){

         mail= new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();

         mail.setToAddresses(new String[] {c.Email});
         mail.setSubject('Test Mail Trigger');
         mail.setPlainTextBody('Hi  you have changed your email Id'+ old.Email +'to ' + c.Email);
         messages.add(mail);
    }
 }
Messaging.sendEmail(messages);
```

}